# Check a chars subset in order of a char string

Tags: algorithm

All:

I want to check if a string1 contains all chars in string2 in order, I wonder how can I do that?

```
For example:

string1 = "abcdeda"
string2 = "ba"

it will return true because by removing first a and cded you can left ba which matches.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
index = -1
str1 = "abcdeda"
str2 = "ba"

for c in str2
    tmp = indexOf(c , str1 , index)
    if tmp != -1
        index = tmp
    else
        return //no match at c

indexOf(c , str , index): first index of c in str after index, or -1,  i
                          if no occurence was found
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally get this. But should index increase by 1?

Comment: no, index is always the index of the last character you searched. this way you only run over str1 once and ensure that the characters of str2 are in the correct order in str1

Comment: Oh, I C, I did not read the note about indexOf, it auto increase in that function.  Do you know any algorithm can run in O(n) time complexity?

Comment: I don't think there's any more efficient solution. This algorithm is only iterating once over both str1 and str2 - split up into multiple steps for str2 - during the complete execution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String string1 = "abcdeda"
String string2 = "ba"

Bool isFound;

for(int i = 0; i < string2.length; i++ ) {
    isFound = false;
    for(int y = 0; y < string1.length; y++ ) {
        if(string2[i] == string1[y]) {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(!isFound) {
        return false;
    } 
}

return true;
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclear expression, my problem requires that the char in string 2 must in same order in string1, I do not quite understand how your code to make sure of that..